# Ember Data returning a structured JSON

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've been working with Ember Data for a while now and I'm mostly happy with it. I like the way that it has forced me to structure my REST api in a sensible way.

I'm coming into a few problems tho, here's one of them: I was using a model with a flat structure before:

```
App.Pageview = DS.Model.extend({
  event: attr('string'),
  value: attr('string'),
  time: attr('date'),
  count: attr('number')
});
```

In this case value was a url all in one string. This model would work fine with JSON that would look like this:

```
{
  "event" : "pageview",
  "value" : "google.com/some/page",
  "time" : "2013-01-31T16:30:00.000Z",
  "count" : 14
}
```

I've changed the way the JSON is structured in the database to make it easier to query so now it looks like this:

```
{
  "event" : "pageview",
  "value" : {
    "url" : "google.com/some/page",
    "domain" : "google.com",
    "path" : "/some/page"
  },
  "time" : "2013-01-31T16:30:00.000Z",
  "count" : 14
}
```

But now i don't really know where to go with things. I tried doing things like this:

```
App.Pageview = DS.Model.extend({
  event: attr('string'),
  value: {
      domain: attr('string'),
      url: attr('string'),
      path: attr('string')
  },
  time: attr('date'),
  count: attr('number')
});
```

But that didn't seem to work, I tested it like this:

```
  console.log(item.get('value'));
  console.log(item.get('value.domain'));
  // console.log(item.get('value').get('domain')); // throws 
  console.log(item.get('value').domain);
```

And got the following results: http://d.pr/i/izDD

So I did some more digging and found that i should probably do something like this:

```
App.Pageview = DS.Model.extend({
  event: attr('string'),
  value: DS.belongsTo('App.SplitUrl', {embedded:true}),
  time: attr('date'),
  count: attr('number')
});

App.SplitUrl = DS.Model.extend({
  domain: attr('string'),
  url: attr('string'),
  path: attr('string')
});
```

But this doesn't work because of an error i get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
```

This usually happens when I have sent an object down my REST api without an id. Here is the exact response from my REST api:

http://d.pr/n/UyW0

Note: i've overloaded the Adapter so that it expects the id to be in the _id field so that it can work better/easier with mongodb. This is how I have overloaded the Adapter:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    serializer: DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
      primaryKey: function(type) {
        return '_id';
      }
    }), 
    namespace: 'api'
  })
});
```

Can anyone help me figure this one out?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/53. Unfortunately, it's still open. I suggest not to use nested object currently and instead just use separate attributes `domain_value`, `url_value`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using ember-data revision 11, try to configure your value as embedded in the adapter instead.

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.SplitUrl',{value:{ embedded:'always'}});
```

Comment: That didn't work but its probably because the fact that i've overloaded the adapter and DS.RESTAdapter doesn't refer to the right instance. I'll update my question to show the code for how up overloaded the Adapter

Comment: I've actually found a good example of how to do this in a test that is designed for my scenario. https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/1ce3052594312aecfb565189ccc6e16c2988e95a/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/embedded/embedded_without_ids_test.js

I'll check it out, see if works and report back.

Comment: Great, please share your findings later on.

Comment: Do you want to post back what worked for you because what @Ken suggested came from the link you pasted . Thanks.

Comment: how do you write map if say SplitUrl -> hasOne -> Value -> hasONe -> Foo .Ember data does not load nested heirarchy if I try to write additional map for App.Value,{foo: {embedded:'always'} Kindly help. Need to use it for Mongo backed Ember